# It is possible to remove expectation operators of both sides?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

While I solve macro model, I derived this equation (using lagrangian method).

$$E_{t}(\mu_{t+1} + \omega_{t+1}) = E_{t}(\omega_{t+1}R_{t+1}) $$

With this equation, could I remove both expectation operator of each side and extract the equation below?

$$ \mu_{t+1} + \omega_{t+1} = \omega_{t+1}R_{t+1} $$

I think this could violate the law of expectation, but not sure of the exact principle.

Comment: No, this is in general false.

Answer (score 1):

Consider two probability distribtions on the space $\{-1,0,1\}$.

\begin{align}
    P(-1) &= P(1) = \frac{1}{2}\\
    P(0) &= 0\\
    Q(-1) &= Q(1) = 0\\
    Q(0) &= 1.
\end{align}
Clearly $E(P) = 0 = E(Q)$, but $P\neq Q$.